# Update WCF service reference to WebService issue in VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, web-services

My current project is using VS 2010. I'm new to WCF. I've consumed WebServices before but I've never had to generate the actual proxy. The current project I'm working on using WCF service reference to call a web service. Fairly simple and straightforward. I've added a new service reference and everything worked perfectly on the initial setup.

When the WSDL was updated, I simply right-clicked on the service reference and selected "Update Reference". After doing so, there are now duplicate object names with the number '1' appened. So for example:

Initial generate from WSDL results:

```
GetWidget (getWidgetRequest)
GetWidgets (getWidgetRequest)
GetWidgetGroups (getWidgetRequest)
```

After updating, I now have this:

```
GetWidget (getWidgetRequest)
GetWidgets (getWidgetRequest)
GetWidgetGroups (getWidgetRequest)

GetWidget1 (getWidgetRequest1)
GetWidgets1 (getWidgetRequest1)
GetWidgetGroups1 (getWidgetRequest1)
```

So now I have to use the GetWidget1 method to use the "updated" service method. My questions are:

1. Is there a way to overwrite the previous methods without generating new types to accomodate the update?
2. Do I have to manually clean this up *every time* the WSDL is updated?
3. Am I updating the service reference incorrectly? Do I need to use the svcutil.exe?

---

I found 4 files within the service reference ending in .datasource. They all have the new typename (GetWidget1.datasource, GetWidgetGroups1.datasource, etc.). Below is a sample of the contents of the file:

```
<GenericObjectDataSource DisplayName="GetWidget1" Version="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
   <TypeInfo>GetWidget1, Service References.WidgetService.Reference.cs, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</TypeInfo>
</GenericObjectDataSource>
```

---

We're using Visual Studio 2010 version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel

Answer (score 1):

You're using vs 2010?

This was a bug in older versions but was fixed in 2010 - see [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/505636/update-or-configure-an-existing-service-reference-in-sl-application-you-get-duplicate-binding-and-endpoint-information)

Comment: It seems quite a few people still get this in VS2010 - not sure what the cause is, but have you tried dropping the reference alltogether and readding it?

Comment: Interestingly enough, I am using VS 2010 though. That appears to be the issue, but I'm not sure why it's still occurring. I believe I've applied all the Service Packs and updates.

Comment: Yes, I have dropped it (the service reference) and readded it (with a new name even) and I still get the duplicate binding and endpoints. It's maddening.

Comment: try dropping the reference and then removing your ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file - this seems to be where the issue lives.

Comment: Before I try that, I found 4 datasource files within the actual service reference that I didn't see before. They're appropriately named: GetWidget1.datasource. I'll update the post above to display the contents.

Comment: I'd recommend you remove those too for good measure. Don't know why it leaves so much bloat behind it when you drop a reference.

Comment: I'm not sure where the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig is. I've searched or it and I've come up empty. Actually, when I readded the reference to the wsdl, those files appeared. So strange. They were not there when things initially worked.